# FlexLayout with DataTemplate alignment

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

My problem is the following. I would like to make the items align like this inside my flex layout (talking about the pictures):

[image]

But I don't know why is my code not working. It works fine with other elements, but it just doesn't work properly when I put this inside . Is there anybody who would know?

Here is the code snippet:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ImagesJson">
        <FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">
            <VerticalStackLayout FlexLayout.Basis="40%">
                <Image Source="{Binding MainImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="150"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </FlexLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

The current behavior is that it puts all images on top of each other instead of next to each other:

[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" - how are we supposed to know what this means?  Please describe the specific problem, or post a screenshot illustrating the behavior

Comment: Edit with current behavior added.

Comment: Why are you putting a FlexLayout inside a CollectionView's ItemTemplate and why do you also have a StackLayout in there? That's way too complicated and also terrible for performance. Please show your ItemsSource, it will make providing an answer easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this using a [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout) instead of a CollectionView:

```xml
<FlexLayout
    Wrap="Wrap"
    Direction="Row"
    JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image
                Source="{Binding MainImage}" 
                Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="150"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

Your current setup is overly complicated and will likely suffer from poor performance apart from the issue you're running into already now. Nesting so many layouts usually isn't a great idea.